# What is the difference between "too" and "as well"?

Tags: differences

What is the difference between "I like apples and I like oranges, too" and "I like apples and I like oranges as well" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are probably some contexts in which you can use only one of these, but I can't think of any. For most purposes they are completely interchangeable.

[Of course, *too* has another, completely different meaning - "excessively" - and you can't use *as well* for that.

Comment: I'm as well tired to argue with your answer. +1.

Comment: ^vote with a note: That extra meaning of *too* can too often make the word ambiguous, if only momentarily, in the middle of a sentence. As in that last sentence, "can too" or "too often"?